# How will I disallow specific characters in AngularJS Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I tried this to disallow characters

`<input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" ng-pattern="/[^\@\-#\-&]/">`

but it's not working.

Comment: What characters do you want to disallow? `@`, `#`, `&`, and `-`? Then try `"/^[^@#&-]*$/"`

Comment: You have to add your `ng-model` to your input: `ngPattern` adds the pattern validator to `ngModel`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew it works. Can you post it on answer so I can select it as the right/correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ralcazar: I posted the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disallow `@`, `#`, `&`, and `-`  characters, use `"/^[^@#&-]*$/"`:

```
<input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" ng-model="YOUR_MODEL" ng-pattern="/^[^@#&-]*$/" />
```

The `^[^@#&-]*$` pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^@#&-]*` - 0 or more chars other than the ones defined in the **negated character class**
- `$` -  end of string.

**Note**: to make the value required, you may add `required` attribute, or replace the `*` quantifier in the pattern with `+` (to require at least 1 (or more) characters).

Comment: `^@#&-`  means except these set of character. +1 for explaination

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example of [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) excluding @, #, &, and - characters with the use of [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): `/^[^@#&-]+$/`:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
      $scope.full_name = '';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="form">
    <label for="full_name">This input is restricted by the current pattern: </label>
    <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" ng-model="full_name" ng-pattern="/^[^@#&-]+$/" /><br>
    <hr>
    Input valid? = <code>{{form.full_name.$valid}}</code><br>
    Model value = <code>{{full_name}}</code>
  </form>
</div>
```